# Why when drawing a box the lines connections/corners have spaces they are not connected ? And why the top front line is missing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The lines are not connected there are spaces in each connection.
And the front top line is missing. In the List allLines there are 12 lines but it's drawing only 11.

What I want is to draw a complete box using the lines and to move the single object with the lines.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShowMeshBounds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objectsToDraw;
    public GameObject prefabEffect;
    public Color color = Color.green;

    private Vector3 v3FrontTopLeft;
    private Vector3 v3FrontTopRight;
    private Vector3 v3FrontBottomLeft;
    private Vector3 v3FrontBottomRight;
    private Vector3 v3BackTopLeft;
    private Vector3 v3BackTopRight;
    private Vector3 v3BackBottomLeft;
    private Vector3 v3BackBottomRight;

    private float counter = 0;
    public bool animateLines;
    public float speed = 1f;

    private List<GameObject> allLines = new List<GameObject>();
    private List<GameObject> instancesToMove = new List<GameObject>();
    private Vector3 endPos;

    private void Start()
    {
        DrawObjects();
    }

    private void DrawObjects()
    {
        objectsToDraw = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("SpawnObject");

        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToDraw.Length; i++)
        {
            CalcPositons(objectsToDraw[i]);
            DrawBox();

            for (int x = 0; x < allLines.Count; x++)
            {

                allLines[x].transform.parent = objectsToDraw[i].transform;
            }
        }

        DuplicatePrefabEffects(1);

        StartCoroutine(moveStuff());
    }

    private void DuplicatePrefabEffects(int duplicationNumber)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < duplicationNumber; i++)
        {
            var go = Instantiate(prefabEffect);
            go.tag = "Duplicated Prefab";
            go.name = "Duplicated Prefab";
            instancesToMove.Add(go);
        }
    }

    void CalcPositons(GameObject objectToDrawTransform)
    {
        Bounds bounds = objectToDrawTransform.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh.bounds;

        Vector3 v3Center = bounds.center;
        Vector3 v3Extents = bounds.extents;

        v3FrontTopLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front top left corner
        v3FrontTopRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front top right corner
        v3FrontBottomLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front bottom left corner
        v3FrontBottomRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z - v3Extents.z);  // Front bottom right corner
        v3BackTopLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back top left corner
        v3BackTopRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y + v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back top right corner
        v3BackBottomLeft = new Vector3(v3Center.x - v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back bottom left corner
        v3BackBottomRight = new Vector3(v3Center.x + v3Extents.x, v3Center.y - v3Extents.y, v3Center.z + v3Extents.z);  // Back bottom right corner

        v3FrontTopLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontTopLeft);
        v3FrontTopRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontTopRight);
        v3FrontBottomLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontBottomLeft);
        v3FrontBottomRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3FrontBottomRight);
        v3BackTopLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackTopLeft);
        v3BackTopRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackTopRight);
        v3BackBottomLeft = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackBottomLeft);
        v3BackBottomRight = objectToDrawTransform.transform.TransformPoint(v3BackBottomRight);
    }

    void DrawBox()
    {
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopLeft, v3FrontTopRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopRight, v3FrontBottomRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomRight, v3FrontBottomLeft, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomLeft, v3FrontTopLeft, color);

        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackTopLeft, v3BackTopRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackTopRight, v3BackBottomRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackBottomRight, v3BackBottomLeft, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3BackBottomLeft, v3BackTopLeft, color);

        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopLeft, v3BackTopLeft, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontTopRight, v3BackTopRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomRight, v3BackBottomRight, color);
        SpawnLineGenerator(v3FrontBottomLeft, v3BackBottomLeft, color);
    }

    void SpawnLineGenerator(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, Color color)
    {
        GameObject myLine = new GameObject();

        myLine.tag = "FrameLine";
        myLine.name = "FrameLine";

        myLine.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        myLine.AddComponent<EndHolder>();
        myLine.GetComponent<EndHolder>().EndVector = end;
        LineRenderer lr = myLine.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Particles/Alpha Blended Premultiply"));
        lr.startColor = color;
        lr.useWorldSpace = false;
        lr.endColor = color;
        lr.startWidth = 0.1f;//0.03f;
        lr.endWidth = 0.1f;//0.03f;
        lr.SetPosition(0, start);
        lr.SetPosition(1, start);

        allLines.Add(myLine);
    }

    IEnumerator moveStuff()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < allLines.Count; i++)
        {
            counter = 0;
            endPos = allLines[i].GetComponent<EndHolder>().EndVector;

            while (Vector3.Distance(instancesToMove[0].transform.position, endPos) > 0.1f)
            {
                counter++;
                endPos = allLines[i].GetComponent<EndHolder>().EndVector;
                Vector3 startPos = allLines[i].GetComponent<LineRenderer>().GetPosition(0);

                instancesToMove[0].transform.position =
                    Vector3.MoveTowards(startPos, endPos, counter / 25f * speed);

                allLines[i].GetComponent<LineRenderer>().SetPosition(1, instancesToMove[0].transform.position);

                yield return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm moving single one object instancesToMove[0] with the lines.
But in the end the result is:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Because `counter` only gets to 23.

With this line:

```
 while(Vector3.Distance(instancesToMove[0].transform.position, endPos) > 0.1f)
```

You check to see if the remaining distance is greater than 0.1, which, if this is true, increment counter, and update the lengths.

When `counter` is 23, this line gets called:

```
v = Vector3.MoveTowards(startPos, endPos, counter / 25f * speed);
```

The value of `t` (the third paramter) is 0.92, this results in the resulting value `v` (which you have as a transform.position, but it then uses that value for the line pos as well) to be `0.46`.

The distance, then, from where it is (`0.46`) and where it wants to be (`0.5`) is then `0.04` which is less than `0.1` and your while loop terminates.  You should check for a much smaller value (or just compare with your `counter`).

Additionally, you're missing an edge:

[image: Missing edge]

This is because the end point of the previous edge is in the same spot as the end point for this edge, but the start is in a completely different spot. You need to relocate your drawing prefab, *then* calculate the distance. *Or* use the distance from the *start* to the *end* and not involve your drawing prefab's position at all.

Comment: I first tried only to change the distance check instead 0.1f to 0.001f and it made the lines almost completed attached without any spaces there is a very small space in the connections. But still it didn't draw the last line. Then I changed also the while to while (Vector3.Distance(startPos, endPos) > 0.001f) I moved the startPos to the top of the script and then doing before the while: startPos = allLines[i].GetComponent<LineRenderer>().GetPosition(0); but now it's drawing only one line. This is what I did: https://pastebin.com/eGcF2WHS

Comment: And here I'm calculating the distance over again each loop then re calculating the distance again inside the while. It's still drawing it with the missing line and with a very small space/s yet. https://pastebin.com/qidHqP8k

Comment: Try `while (counter < 25)`